# Wait until all http GET requests done before logging to console in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-request

Javascript/Node noob here. Having some trouble with understanding the whole asynchronous aspect of JS.  I am building a small app that's purpose is to make calls to an external API and then store the results for logging purposes.

Anyway, I have a GET request that looks like this

```
request(callsOptions)
.then(function (res) {
    //Request success... do some logic with the response object
    var content = JSON.stringify(res)
    //save result to a file with the name as m-d-yyyy.json
    fs.writeFile(`callLogs/${month}-${day}-${year}.json`, content, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    })        
    //get session_ids and call destinations and store in the 2 diff arrays
    var calls = res.calls
    for(let x = 0; x < calls.length; x++){
        session_ids[x] = calls[x].session_id
        dests[x] = calls[x].dest
    }
    //make an individual req for each call in the array
    for(let x = 0; x < calls.length; x++){
        getCallLog(session_ids[x], dests[x])
    }
}).catch(function (err) {
    //Request failure...
    console.log('Whoops... something went wrong with the calls request!')
})
```

This then calls the getCallLog method, which takes the info extracted from the previous request and makes a bunch more calls

```
function getCallLog(id, dest){
request(constructURL(id))
    .then(function (res) {
        //Request success... do some logic with the response object
        console.log('Request success!')
        var content = JSON.stringify(res)
        fs.writeFile(`${dest}/${id}.json`, content, 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        })
        //return res
    }).catch(function (err) {
        //Request failure...
        console.log('Whoops... something went wrong with the call request!')
    })
```

}

So, I want to wait until AFTER all the GET requests have completed to do some logic. For now, that logic will simply be something like

```
    console.log('DONE')
```

The problem is everything I've tried will show DONE before its done due to the asynchronous aspect of JS. So, I'm just stuck waiting for a bit to make sure all the requests have finished.

Things I've tried:

- putting an if statement in the for-loop for when the loop completes
- using a counter in the getCallLog().then() function

EDIT: like this?

```
    const { promisify } = require("util")
```

...

```
request(callsOptions)
    .then(function (res) {
        //Request success... do some logic with the response object
        var content = JSON.stringify(res)
        //save result to a file with the name as m-d-yyyy.json under the callLogs folder
        fs.writeFile(`callLogs/${month}-${day}-${year}.json`, content, 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        })
        //get session_ids and call destinations and store in the 2 diff arrays
        var calls = res.calls
        for (let x = 0; x < calls.length; x++) {
            session_ids[x] = calls[x].session_id
            dests[x] = calls[x].dest
        }
        //make an individual req for each call in the array
        const promises = [];
        for (let x = 0; x < calls.length; x++) {
            promises.push(getCallLog(session_ids[x], dests[x]))
        }
        return Promise.all(promises)
    }).then(function(){
        console.log("All done!")
    }).catch(function (err) {
        //Request failure...
        fs.writeFile(`errorlog/${month}-${day}-${year}.json`, content, 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        })
    })

function getCallLog(id, dest){
request(constructURL(id))
    .then(function (res) {
        //Request success... do some logic with the response object 
        console.log('Request success!')
        var content = JSON.stringify(res)
        return promisify(fs.writeFile)(`${dest}/${id}.json`, content, 'utf8');
    }).catch(function (err) {
        //Request failure...
        fs.writeFile(`errorlog/${month}-${day}-${year}-${id}.json`, err, 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        })
    })
    }
```

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/8252164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return a promise from the inner function and promisify the file writing:

```
const { promisify } = require("util");

function getCallLog(id, dest){
  return request(constructURL(id)) // <-- return the promise
   .then(function (res) {
      //Request success... do some logic with the response object
      console.log('Request success!')
      var content = JSON.stringify(res)
      return promisify(fs.writeFile)(`${dest}/${id}.json`, content, 'utf8');
  }).catch(function (err) { // also catches writing errors
    console.log('Whoops... something went wrong with the call request!')
  });
}
```

Now you can collect all the promises in.your loop:

```
const promises = [];
for(let x = 0; x < calls.length; x++){
    promises.push(getCallLog(session_ids[x], dests[x]));
}
```

And then return these promises into the chain:

```
return Promise.all(promises);
```

So now you can add a `.then(...)` to the chain that will get executed afterwards:

```
.then(() => console.log("All done!"));
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. When you say return the promises into the chain, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @otterjesus https://medium.com/@justintulk/flattening-nested-promises-in-javascript-88f04793ded7

Comment: I'm not sure if I implemented it wrong, but it seems like its still sending "DONE" in the console before all the requests have resolved. See the Edit in the OP for the code

Comment: @otter you have to `return request(...)` !!

Comment: Oh... Whoops! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Glad to help :)